# Extracting Data From Natural Resources Canada - Canada west coast topo-bathymetric digital elevation model

Tags: raster, color

I have been trying to figure out how to extract a single color DEM from this dataset available on Natural Resource Canada's Website,

https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/e6e11b99-f0cc-44f7-f5eb-3b995fb1637e

It is available to view in ArcGIS Rest, WMS, and download a FGDB/GDB. I loaded this into QGIS using all the methods and tried to save raster as a GeoTIFF which just gave me RGB with no elevations. I have read up on the form that WMS does not give data.

Is there another way to save this with elevations?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that WMSs don't contain elevation data. Unfortunately, you can only open rasters from a GDB within ESRI software like ArcGIS Pro (see image below). See here for more info: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html. In QGIS, you can only open vector data from GDBs.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that makes things more clear. I was wondering that. I will either have to get ArcGIS personal or see if the data owner can send me a different file format that I can open in QGIS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For what it's worth, it is possible to export your raster data from a file geodatabase with [ArcRasterRescue](https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue).